# Stymied in search for an electronic lock

Tags: motor, inductor, mechanical

I'm looking for an electronic lock to secure a small, wooden box (breadbox-sized). The box is ordinary: one side of the lid is hinged against one side of the box.

When I look for 'electronic locks' in a search engine, I don't get anything that would do: either expensive, bulky door locks (too big and don't hold in the right direction for a box) or just magnets (which won't hold once the power is cut). I just want something small, which requires power and a signal to release the catch/bolt.

Where should I look or what search term should I use?

(I know this may not be apropos here, but I don't see a stackexchange site where it's more relevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is a small motor with a shaped stick that locks into a slot. If you want it to be more robust, you can just use the motor to stick the bar into the slot, without relying on its robustness.

[image]

Another idea is a coil, but it's easily opened by a magnet.

**IMPORTANT:** Remember that with an electric lock, you are subject to the reliability and battery/supply to the circuit. In case something fails, make sure you have an alternative (not that good for a lock).